# Trying to translate proxy deployment script from Truffle to Buidler. Not sure how

Tags: truffle, buidler

I have a custom proxy. Writing a deployment script for Buidler. Know how to do something in Truffle but not sure how to do the equivalent in Buidler.

**Truffle**

```
let testContract = await deployer.deploy(TestContract);
let customProxy = await deployer.deploy(CustomProxy, testContract.address, <param>);
let testContractCast = await TestContract.at(customProxy.address);
```

**Buidler**

```
let testContract = await deployContract(wallet, TestContract);
let customProxy = await deployContract(wallet, CustomProxy, [testContract.address, <param>])
let testContractCast = ???
```

Comment: Buidler is now [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org).

Comment: Not sure if helps but OpenZeppelin wrote a plugin for Hardhat, which deals with [upgradeable proxies](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it should work according to the documentation. Please let us know if it does indeed work.

As described in https://github.com/nomiclabs/buidler/tree/master/packages/buidler-ethers#environment-extensions, the buidler-ethers plugin adds a `getContractAt` object to the ethers object.

What that means for you would be

1. Install the plugin if not yet done.

```bash
$ npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/buidler-ethers 'ethers@^5.0.0'
```

And add the following statement to your `buidler.config.js`:

```js
usePlugin("@nomiclabs/buidler-ethers");
```

2. Now you can use it in your script:

```js
const myEthersContract = await ethers.getContractAt(nameOrAbi, atAddress);
```

Comment: i'm getting a `function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function` error when I do this. Buidler thinks i'm linking up with the proxy abi even though i need to use the implementation contract ABI @markus

Comment: @MichaelC are you using `TestContract.abi` for the `nameOrAbi` ?

Comment: yes, `TestContract.abi`

Comment: the issue was that i was using the receive keyword instead of the fallback keyword in my proxy